# Изображение не больше родителя

Tags: html, css

Как сделать что бы большие изображение со свойством `width:auto` не становилось больше родителя `div`?
`width:100%` не подходит так как растягиваются малые изображения.

Comment: max-width: 100% ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно использовать [`max-width: 100%`](https://webref.ru/css/max-width).

Большие изображения будут пропорционально уменьшены и вписаны в родительский блок.
Маленькие изображения будут показаны без изменений.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 200px;
}
.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p><img class="image" src="https://satyr.io/50x50/50"></p>
  <p><img class="image" src="https://satyr.io/300x50/300"></p>
</div>
```